# How to covert array of shape n, to n,m

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying convert numpy array of shape `(80000,)` to `(80000,55)`
I'm having the data like below
`[[1212,121,121],[12,122,111]]`
After convert this list of list I'm getting the shape of `(2,)` but I wanna have shape like `(2,3)` how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [68]: np.array([[1212,121,121],[12,122,111]] )                                                               
Out[68]: 
array([[1212,  121,  121],
       [  12,  122,  111]])
In [69]: _.shape                                                                                                
Out[69]: (2, 3)
```

If you are getting a shape like (2,), it's probably because some of the nested lists differ in shape.  Check the `dtype` as well as the `shape`.  Look at the array as well.

```
In [70]: np.array([[1212,121,121],[12,122,111,3]] )                                                             
Out[70]: array([list([1212, 121, 121]), list([12, 122, 111, 3])], dtype=object)
```

An upcoming version will add a warning:

```
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
```